# Xcode - Dark theme for the whole UI

Tags: xcode, macos, user-interface, themes

How can one make Xcode's UI completely dark?

There must be a way to have a dark theme for Xcode (like Visual Studio has it for example). I'm not only talking about a way of styling the editor, but a full-on dark theme. Dark menus, dark console, dark file browser, dark menu bar, etc.

Xcode's bright UI hurts at night and I can't be the only one who's really searching for this ;)   (please don't recommand f.lux to me now, that's not a solution)

Comment: Just spent a while trying to figure this out. I honestly can't believe there isn't any way to do this

Comment: I also wish there was a way.

Comment: Move this to apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable Dark Mode for Xcode 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50696931/how-to-enable-dark-mode-for-xcode-10)

Answer (score 29):

Xcode's UI can be changed to completely dark with Xcode 10 running on macOS Mojave. Just go into System Preferences -> General -> Under Appearance -> Click the dark mode

[image: Enable Dark Appearance mode]

[image]

Comment: What is your experience with Mojave so far? Is everything working correctly when it comes to iOS development? I always used Xcode beta, but I'm a little scared of macOS beta. :)

Comment: @ĐorđeNilović I built a few new features off of it and it was great. I built a production build to release to the App Store using Xcode command line tools and fastlane using Xcode 9.4.1. But all my code and features were completed using Xcode 10 and on macOS Majave. I love it. None of the know bugs have effected me.

Answer (score 7):

If you need Dark theme for the whole UI, here is what you need to do:

1: Open Xcode settigns

[image]

2: Click Appearance and select Dark

[image]

Done!

Comment: ChatGPT didn't know that :(

Answer (score 5):

You can reference to this article:

https://medium.com/@guilhermerambo/how-to-enable-real-dark-mode-on-os-x-macos-14966f9f7d24

Install a dark mode in system service,it make Xcode most control dark,it's not perfect, but works.

Hope Apple implement it someday.

Comment: I've seen this....and nearly did it. But it was too scary in the end to disable the system security measures. Have you tested it? I've not seen screenshots of dark mode Xcode yet with this hack.

Comment: I have disable SIP previous, so I don't care it.Here is the result image, https://ibb.co/g6oUiv

Comment: Thanks, that looks rather cool actually. Just a pity that not all bright white is gone.

Comment: and they did it!

Answer (score 4):

In `Preferences → Accessibility` there is a checkbox `Invert colors`. Of course, it doesn't give a nice dark theme, but I found it quite useful when working in darkness. The whole system interface with this checkbox on looks funny.

Answer (score 3):

System wide dark mode is announced in *macOS 10.14* Mojave in WWDC 18. You can also enable dark mode for **XCode 10**. Dark mode in interface builder.
[image: Dark mode in XCode]

Here is the link for [XCode 10 beta](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)

Comment: But the question is, Are we able to use this theme on Xcode 10 beta and macOS 10.13 or not? I think it won't be possible.

Comment: You need `macOS Mojave` to get dark mode in XCode 10. As dark mode is OS feature.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 9 or below you can include the last the theme Dark,

https://gist.github.com/andresilvagomez/94854ed5320fac2b3b5790e63efc516e

Execute this command

open ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes/

and create this file there

Default (Dark).xccolortheme

and paste the content inside of URL

Comment: This theme does not add dark sidebar or window headers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think Xcode can do that. You might want to consider the excellent [Appcode](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/?fromMenu) IDE though.

Answer (score -3):

This works in Xcode 9:

Xcode --> Preferences.. --> Fonts & Colors tab --> Choose your them (Dusk / Midnight)

Comment: Please feel free to share why you downvoted and I will try to help.

Comment: It does not change the sidebar or windows headers to dark mode. That's why the downvote.

Comment: Thanks kakubei, that's probably it.

Comment: @DrorBar That just makes the code editor and console dark. Not the whole xcode ide