# How to enable Dark Mode for Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode10, macos-high-sierra

Apple announced a new Dark Mode for Xcode 10. I've downloaded the beta but now I can't find any option to turn it on. I'm currently on macOS 10.13 High Sierra.

[image]

Answer (score 93, accepted):

#### On macOS 10.13 High Sierra and earlier

The Dark Mode is only available on macOS 10.14 Mojave.

#### On macOS 10.14 Mojave and later

**1. On Installation:** You'll get asked for the appearance as part of the installation of Mojave.

[image]

**2. After Installation:** If you want to change it afterwards go to `System Preferences` > `General` and change the `Appearance`.

[image]

**2b. On macOS Catalina:**
You get even a third option to change the appearance automatically based on your Nightshift preferences.

[image]

Comment: in this way i should turn on dark mode for the whole OS. isn't there a way to open only XCode in dark mode?

Comment: As far as I know, no. But for Xcode you have at least the option to change the editor theme.

Answer (score 12):

If you use macOS Mojave (10.14.+), you can enable Dark Mode only for Xcode 10 using this command line.

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSWindowDarkChocolate -bool true
```

**Workaround**:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode _NSSystemAppearanceOverride DarkAppearance
```

[Source](https://twitter.com/stroughtonsmith/status/1009385685248245760) (Steve Troughton-Smith's tweet)

Comment: You should mention that this only makes some elements "dark", but it isn't actually usable.

Comment: @JonathanTaylor Did you tried with Xcode 10 on Mojave ? Xcode on version < macOS 10.14 will make only some elements dark like you said. That's why I write "If you use on macOS Mojave" ;)

Comment: @Maximelc not working. I have Light mode enabled and this command doesn't make the Xcode dark (Mojave 10.14/Xcode 10.0)

Comment: @RomanSlyepko - https://twitter.com/stroughtonsmith/status/1009385685248245760?lang=da

Comment: @Kaisp not working since Mojave beta 4 

Comment: @RomanSlyepko 

Comment: Not working now.